# iTunes XML: entity name must immediately follow the &

Tags: xml, exception, itunes, dropbox, feed

I am receiving the same error message again and again. I have consulted the different threads on stackoverflow but couldn't find a solution for this case.

I am trying to submit a podcast xml on itunes and the following error message keeps re-occurring:

> Invalid XML: Error on line13: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>"Schreiberlein"</title>
  <description>Auf dem Weg zum Autor. Seid dabei an der Entwicklung meines ersten Romans 
  und fühlt euch dazu inspiriert, selbst "Stift" anzulegen.</description>
  <link>https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kt4y1ihjmmczwtd/TUmghSJ7Vp</link>
  <language>de-ch</language>
  <copyright>2013</copyright>
  <author>Schreiberlein</author>
  <image href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/twjff2aetj9oj0k/steffipodcast.jpg" />
  <category text="Arts &amp; Literature" />
  <item>
     <title>"Schreiberlein Episode 1</title>
     <description>Intro</description>
     <link>https://www.dropbox.com/s/nbaivy67d4h0w25/Episode1.mp3</link>
     <enclosure url=" https://www.dropbox.com/s/nbaivy67d4h0w25/Episode1.mp3" length=" 
     1123968" type=" audio/mpeg" />
     <guid>https://www.dropbox.com/s/nbaivy67d4h0w25/Episode1.mp3</guid>
     <pubDate>Mon, 13 Jan 2014 23:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
     <keywords>schreiberlein, schreiben, roman, text, texten, kreativ, 
     autor, schriftsteller</keywords>
     <duration>DURATION 0:01:10</duration>
     <explicit>no</explicit>
  </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I would appreciate your assistance a lot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't told us _what_ is issuing the error. Your XML is perfectly valid, so there may be a more stringent requirement in whatever's processing the XML.  It's also a little strange that the only `&amp;` is in line 12, not line 13.

Comment: Hi Jim
I am trying to submit the XML on itunes. I enter the dropbox link to the xml document on itunes when the error message appears. Actually, the same error message appeared already before I added the &amp; entry. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried submitting the XML to [Feed Validator](http://feedvalidator.org/) as recommended by Apple? This may provide more information.  Also, from a cursory scan of the Apple podcast submission pages I think you may need to include the proper `itunes:` namespace and use it for the iTunes-specific tags.  I've never done this so you'll have to do the research or wait (maybe a long time) for someone with podcast submission experience to help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yeah, the Feed Validator tells me it's a webpage and not a feed. Maybe I need to choose another server other than dropbox? I had the namespace itunes: in there before and it didn't go through either. I guess I'll just go through the whole itunes support page again.

Comment: Shot in the dark: remove the leading spaces in your attribute values.

Comment: I suggest you research the use of namespaces in your XML and try to find something showing a sample XML that works.

Comment: My guess is that for some reason, the XML you are parsing is the original incorrect XML before you made the correction. Perhaps you're picking up a cached copy or something like that. Try introducing a deliberate error before line 12 and see if the parser reports it.

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried some mock links and then it would come up with other errors. I refreshed and cleared caches and cookies so I think I can exclude that.

Comment: Does anybody know if Dropbox is an accepted server for itunes XML feeds?
I uploaded a xml document (programm: windows editor) on dropbox and try to submit the link on itunes. 
Any ideas?